# Setting Default Dynamic Values in Select2 2.4.0?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using the most up-to-date version of Select2. The select2 box is used to display a list of skills. I am trying to set the default values (for when it's opened) to contain the current skills. I have the information in proper format, I just cannot understand how to set it. The closest I've gotten is using:

```
//b is array containing list of user selected options
//#e1 is select2 id
for($i=0;$i<b.length;$i++) $('#e1').val(b[$i]).trigger("change");
```

However, this only displays the LAST option. Which I think is because I'm not allowed to set it in a loop. However I'm unsure how else to do it??

Any current solutions are invalid as of Select v2.4.0 as initSelection and .select2("val", data etc.) was removed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was actually very simple and avoided for loops all together.

```
$('#e1').select2({
//info
}).val(b).trigger("change");
```

[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) in jQuery also accepts arrays.